# Can I bring these foods from the US to the Netherlands? And do I need to declare it?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, netherlands

Firstly, I am so confused by this whole process. When I visited The Netherlands a year ago, I didn't bring anything with me but on the way back I brought alcohol and cheese but never declared it and I didn't have a problem.

That being said, this time I am traveling from New York to Amsterdam in a few weeks. I want to take some indian spices with me. I don't need them in my carry on, I'd like to check them in. Firstly, are there any restrictions on this? I already have the spices and the containers have been opened, would I need to put them in a specific kind of container? Additionally, do I need to declare these items on the customs form to the Netherlands?

What about things like fish sauce, oyster sauce, soy sauce, indian chutneys? Can I still pack it even though the package has been opened? Will I need to put it in a special container and do I need to declare these items to customs?

And last thing: Can I bring sugar on a checked luggage and do I have to declare it? And again, does it matter if the package has been opened already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I take Amul cottage cheese from India to Netherlands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141110/can-i-take-amul-cottage-cheese-from-india-to-netherlands)

Comment: Hard cheese usually isn't a problem but you are very lucky to have not been caught. You can be fined for not declaring food, even if the food is allowed!

Comment: Read the linked answer above, with the quotation from the Netherlands government agency that regulates the importation of foodstuffs from non-EU countries.

Comment: @David none of the things in that quote are things I want to bring. Im asking about spices, sugar, and sauces. the quote is talking about animal products

Comment: @MichaelHampton yikes! I'll make sure to do it next time. what happens when you declare it? do they go through your bag? that was the reason I didn't declare it because I didn't want them to mess up my luggage

Comment: They'll just ask you to show them what food you have. Generally you'll be able to pull it out of your bags yourself when you've declared it. I recommend you pack in such a way that all your food items are together and you can easily separate them from everything else. If you don't declare, and a food sniffing dog alerts on your bag, then they definitely will take everything apart.

Comment: @user477465 The relevant quote in that answer is "In the EU strict requirements apply to the import of animal products and **food**. Examples: cheese, milk and milk products, eggs, meat, fresh or processed fishing products, skins, game trophies. Do you nevertheless still want to import animal products and **food** into the EU? Then you almost always need a health certificate. In your case, what you plan to carry into the EU (sugar, spices, sauces) is stuff that humans eat, i.e. **food**. How does this not apply?

Comment: And I'll add that Michael Hampton's advice to declare what you're carrying is exactly correct. Customs will probably confiscate the food items, and may toss your luggage, but because you declared the things you had you'll not be fined or otherwise hassled.

Comment: @David they will confiscate spices?? even if they are dry spices and I've declared them? also does the packaging matter? if the package has already been opened?

Comment: @user477465. They might, and they might not. I'm risk-averse, and I think Customs would be well within their authority to confiscate them as a food item. If you're willing to risk confiscation, bring and declare them and you'll find out.

Comment: @David i just spoke with an agent in amsterdam schipol airport and they said that what I was planning on bringing is totally fine :)

Comment: @user477465 Great! After you arrive, check back in here and let us know how it went.

Comment: @David Your quote in the answer you are linking to is wrong. Perhaps the page you are linking to was incorrect at that time, but it has been corrected now. There are some restrictions for different kinds of food, mostly products from animals, but fruit, vegetables and plant-based food (also spices) can usually be imported to EU countries for private consumption. The page you are linking to also mentions that 20kg fish can be imported, so I would not even assume that there is a problem with fish or oyster sauce.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The page I quoted is still served at that link, and its content remains the same. The page addresses "food," and contains no mention that ..."fruit, vegetables and plant-based food (also spices) can usually be imported to EU countries for private consumption..." Can you offer another source or citation?

Comment: @David If you look at the site menu of the page you are linking to, import of fruits and vegetables is discussed on the following page. What OP is intending to do here is covered by the 'exception for small quantities' section.

Comment: user477465, you're far more likely to have success with unopened (factory-sealed) packages of spices.  An open container could be infested with undesirable pests, while a factory-sealed container is more or less guaranteed not to be.  Looking at the page on [plants, flowers, fruit and vegetables (phytosanitary products)](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/restricted_prohibited_import_export/plants_flowers_fruit_vegetables/), however, it seems there is no explicit requirement for the containers to be unopened.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo There are four qualifications in the "Exceptions for Small Quantities" section. The last three clearly are satisfied by the OP's plans. The first requires that the stuff (here, vegetables and fruit) to be imported "does not pose a serious risk for spreading harmful organisms." I'd guess that commercially-packaged items would pass this test, but beyond that I have no idea what they'll allow. I agree that this page is a better citation for "fruits and vegetables," but it doesn't actually say if product x will be admitted. It is, I submit, not very useful as a practical guide.

Comment: @David The 'does not pose a serious risk' refer to a small number of items of specific origins, which are listed in different regulations and are subject to restrictions or mandatory inspections due to concrete risks. Examples for this are mushrooms from several east, central and north European countries due to the still present risk of cesium contamination from Chernobyl fallout or pistachios from Iran, which may be contaminated with aflatoxins.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Exactly as I said: very suitable authority-wise for Customs officials, but not terribly useful as a practical guide to the casual traveler.

Answer (score 5):

Dutch Customs has a web portal in English with a description of what is and isn't allowed to be brought in by travelers arriving from outside of the EU [here](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/luggage/from_a_non_eu_country/) with the short recommendation:

> ## What cannot be imported?
>
> Not all products can simply be brought in. Counterfeit articles, for example, or €10,000 or more, **food**, and animals and plants.

Followed by some more specific regulations and exemptions.

Cheese is clear cut and falls under the section of [*"Animal products and foodstuff"*](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/restricted_prohibited_import_export/animal_products_foodstuffs/animal_products_and_foodstuffs) and is only allowed with a health certificate (which is probably not worth the effort to obtain) :

> **Do not import any animal products into the Netherlands from outside the EU**. And also do not order them, for example, through the internet. In the EU strict requirements apply to the import of animal products and food. **Examples: cheese,** milk and milk products, eggs, meat, fresh or processed fishing products, skins, game trophies. Do you nevertheless still want to import animal products and food into the EU? Then you almost always need a health certificate.

The [fruit and vegetable category](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/abroad_and_customs/restricted_prohibited_import_export/plants_flowers_fruit_vegetables/)  which provides and exemption for *"small amounts"* for personal use by the traveler.

> Sometimes you do not need a phytosanitary certificate and you may import your product without a problem. This is the case if the product:
>
> - does not pose a serious risk for spreading harmful organisms
> - when it is taken by travellers themselves as luggage for personal use
>
> ...
>   Have these conditions been observed? If this is the case, you do not need a permit for:
>
> - at most 5 kilos of vegetables or fruit
>
> ...

When the individual animal / fruit / vegetable  component in food is sufficiently processed and not recognisable as such anymore (for instance the milk in a chocolate bar)  food is sometimes allowed. Typical examples of allowed foods are: pastries and cookies, sweets and chocolate.

Spices are allowed when they are

- dried
- don't contain a protected plant species
- don't contain an illegal substance/drug
  <sub>(source: the [Dutch Customs app](https://belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/douane/reisbagage/app_douane_reizen/is_dit_ok), no other online source)</sub>

I don't know of any requirements (other than for infants milk)  for original and unopened packaging.

Please note that something such as oyster sauce and a chutney, if allowed, is considered a liquid and not allowed in your carry-on luggage when in a container larger than 100 ml.

Also consider that The Netherlands, like many affluent countries import food and spices from all over the world and although specific brands may not be available, or hard to source, most if not all supermarkets will sell some variety of fish, oyster and soy sauce and certainly sugar...

Comment: And besides supermarkets there are also specialist shops selling foods from a particular country or a wide range of countries.