# Paneer in the hand-luggage within the EU?

Tags: food-and-drink, eu, hand-luggage

Can I bring a single 1.5 kg package of semi-soft cheese (paneer) to Sweden from Germany in my hand luggage when flying?

I found an [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/141112/118213) which does not rule out bringing paneer on the plane yet it suggests not to do so when flying from a non-EU to an EU country.

Comment: Sweden **is** a EU member, so there aren't any customs restrictions on food

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The main issue here will be airport security, not customs restrictions.

Answer (score 7):

It is from a customs viewpoint no issue to bring food from Germany to Sweden, but the prohibition against fluids in hand luggage also applies to pasty substances. It is not necessarily detected, but if, I would assume that they will not let you through security with the paneer.

Comment: I recently read a piece explaining why the US TSA includes peanut butter in the ban on liquids and gels.  Their criterion is whether the substance maintains its own shape or takes the shape of the container it's in.  If the security service in Germany uses the same criterion then the paneer is probably acceptable.

Comment: Cheese will show up in the X-ray. Probably it will be inspected.

Comment: @phoog I think here, that a lot depends on the mood of the security inspector. I have been refused at the security check in Munich with butter in my hand luggage, so the quoted TSA criterion is obviously not universally applied.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo well butter adds the obvious complication of temperature, but at reasonable room temperatures butter is significantly softer than peanut butter, so I would be extremely surprised if the TSA would ever knowingly allow butter.  hard and semi-soft cheese, however, retains its shape even at a fairly high room temperature.  You're surely right that the officer's mood plays a big role, especially with borderline cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your comments!

Comment: @phoog peanut butter is far softer at room temperature than is butter (real butter that is, not talking about vegetable based margarine).

Comment: @jwenting I don't know whether it's your butter, peanut butter, or room that is different from mine, but what you're saying is not even close to being true in my experience, so it must be at least one of those things.

Comment: @phoog in my experience peanut butter is often almost liquid at room temperature, similar consistently to syrup.

Comment: @phoog I agree with jwenting here, but there may of course be regional differences. Where I live, butter is just sold wrapped in paper and a relatively firm mass even at room temperature. I rarely eat peanut butter, but I would still describe it as a thick, but still runny liquid. If I scoop up a piece of butter with a spoon, the butter will stay in its shape as a piece of butter on the spoon. If I scoop up peanut butter with the spoon, it will run off the spoon if I tilt it. Here are a few pictures of how I know peanut butter: https://pinchofyum.com/5-minute-homemade-peanut-butter

Comment: @jwenting, Tor, well I grew up in the US, where the peanut butter story originates, and there peanut butter is traditionally processed to reduce separation, which yields a stiff product like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/oddlysatisfying/comments/2vxv6c/my_big_spoonful_of_peanut_butter_hrnnnng/ (more natural products have been getting more common in the last few decades).  In the parts of the US where I have lived, during most of the year a stick of butter left on the counter will soften to the point that it collapses under its own weight.

Comment: I'm with phoog.  I have never experienced liquid peanut butter but I have experienced very fluid butter.  It could be down to the style of peanut butter that I like.  Runny peanut butter may be available but I don't buy it.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried carrying cheese in a carry-on between Schengen countries.

Once, I had 2 pieces at the same time:

- One (hard cheese, Comté) was accepted without issue.
- The other (soft cheese, Brie, IIRC) was rejected by the airport security, but the person deciding didn't seem 100% sure. The basis was that it was too close to being liquid, and didn't match the 100mL/1L restrictions.

However, another time I flew with a full wheel of Brie in the cabin, without any problem.

Not a definite answer, only anecdotes, but I would say there is a non-null possibility that your cheese gets rejected.

That being said, there's no need to fly between Sweden and Germany. There are night trains between Stockholm and Hamburg and up to Berlin.